# Oracle virtualbox through windows cmd

Tags: windows, ubuntu, cmd, virtualbox

i have windows 7 and Oracle virtual box installed with linux ubuntu for project files, git ect.

I wannt to use my Webstorm 7 with builtin terminal (point to cmd console). Is there a way for me to get cmd and virtual box to communicate?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the `VBoxManage` command line application - detailed in [Chapter 8](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html) of the VirtualBox documentation.

Chapter 8: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html